# how to see the result of python code in a remote linux server

Tags: python, linux, putty

From a Windows I want to run my python code with putty on a linux remote server. I can work with command line only. I use this code in command line:

```
python3 mycode.py
```

My code starts to run but I cannot see any thing. I use putty for connecting to server. I cannot type any other commands:

[image]

If I restart my connection I cannot see any result too.
I don't have any GUI. How can I see the result my code?

Comment: `cannot open display: localhost:10.0` It's definitely trying to connect to an X server. Are you sure you have no GUI?

Comment: What are you expecting to see? What's the code? Does it run in the terminal on your local computer?

Comment: @Aplet123 The message showed because I wanted to open `gedit` and I couldn't. I enabled X11 in putty but I cannot have a GUI. I think the remote server don't allow me to have a GUI. but how can I see my result?

Comment: @MatsLindh I want to see the result code that is run on remote linux server. No, I run it on the server's terminal.

Comment: Yes, but _what is that result_? Is it text output from the command? Is it launching a window? Exactly what do you expect to get back from launching the python application?

Comment: @MatsLindh My result are some lists that I saved them as .npy file at the end of my code: `np.save('Best_start50It.npy',Best_start)`  But I any files are not built.

Comment: In that case it seems like your code is either running for a long time (and you're not patient enough), you have an infinite loop or your code is waiting for input. Impossible to say without you including the code that's giving you problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to foward the `X11` server:

```
ssh -X user@server
```

Your remote host also needs to be configured to allow `X11` to be forwarded. More details in [this StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46748) reply.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I enabled X11 in putty but I cannot have a GUI. I think the remote server don't allow me to have a GUI. but how can I see my result?

Comment: If you enable X11 forwarding, you also need to install an X server locally on your computer for a GUI to show.